# Is my random generation method flawed? (PHP)

Tags: php, random

I have this small internal project that inserts occasional entries into a MySQL database. I have a column named "idChar" were I set it's value to a randomly generated string using 62 possible characters with a length of 31.

Today I discovered that a new entry just so happened to have the same exact idChar as an entry from several months ago. I am now checking for duplicate entries before saving them, but this made me think about the odds of this happening and I am curious to know if my implementation of generating these random keys is flawed. Getting a duplicate should be roughly 1 in 62^31 right?

```
function getCode($len)
{
    //$len = 10;
    $base='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstwxyz123456789';
    $max=strlen($base)-1;
    $linkCode='';
    mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
    while (strlen($linkCode)<$len+1)
      $linkCode.=$base{mt_rand(0,$max)};

    return $linkCode;
}

$idChar=getCode(30);

//code to insert into MySQL here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The odds of getting a duplicate would be calculated as per the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), because that's how you [calculate the chance of collisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Cast_as_a_collision_problem) for the output of a function that produces a randomly chosen output from a discrete codomain. In effect you want to calculate the chance that among a pool of selections made randomly any two selections are the same.

You should also completely drop the `mt_srand` call as it is not necessary, and it's likely to provide worse seeds than what PHP will do automatically. Consider that the output of `microtime` (in my system at least) is like

```
0.29574400 1348356024
```

which means that you only have 1 million different seeds available as the last two digits of the float are always zeroes and the `(double)microtime()` cast completely ignores the seconds part (it would be a lousy seed anyway).

Assuming that the random number generator produces the same sequence of random numbers whenever it is seeded with the same seed then in effect *you only have 1 million possible random codes instead of 62^31* -- quite a decrease! Fortunately it is documented that [this does not happen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php) on PHP 5.2.1 onwards.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you very much. I was starting to think I stumbled into the 'Heart of Gold.'

1 in a million is much more believable!